# Unable to connect to other instances of the same program via TCP

Tags: c#, tcp

I know this might have been asked a thousand times before, but I can't seem to find any specific information about my case.

I have a C# client program that has to connect to other instances of the client over a LAN. To connect one client to another, I use a TcpListener/TcpClient aproach. Both instances have a listener and are able to create a new client to connect/listen to one another (it is independant of which instance started the connection).

To create the listener, I use the following bit of code:

```
// In the constructor:
listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 32842);
listenThread = new Thread((ThreadStart)ListenForConnections);
listenThread.Name = "ListenThread";
listenThread.IsBackground = true;
listenThread.Start();

// Listening for connections:
private void ListenForConnections()
{
    listener.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Started listening for connections");
    for (; ; )
    {
        if (listener.Pending())
        {
            using (TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
            {
                // My own layer over the TcpClient.
                AsyncTCPClient other = new AsyncTCPClient(client);
                Console.WriteLine("Connection from " + client.Client.RemoteEndPoint);
                other.Received += DataReceived;
                other.Exception += ExceptionOccurred;
                connections.Add("Player", other);
                other.Start();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5);
        }
    }
}
```

To create and connect to another client, I use the following bit of code:

```
public void Connect(IPEndPoint other)
{
    if (socket == null)
    {
        socket = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
        socket.Client.ReceiveBufferSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
    }
    // Should force-close the socket after 5 seconds if it can't be closed automatically.
    socket.LingerState = new LingerOption(true, 5);
    socket.BeginConnect(other.Address, other.Port, ConnectionCallback, other);
    IsConnecting = true;
}
```

The ConnectionCallback given as a parameter to BeginConnect looks like this:

```
private void ConnectionCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    IsConnecting = false;
    IsConnected = socket.Connected;
    if (IsConnected)
    {
        IPEndPoint connectedTo = (IPEndPoint)result.AsyncState;
        stream = socket.GetStream();
        if (Connected != null)
        {
            Connected(this, null);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Exception != null)
        {
            RaiseException(new Exception("Unable to connect to host"));
        }
    }
}
```

However, everytime I get to the callback, the TcpClient failed to connect to the other instance and the Exception event is thrown. Now what I've found while searching around the internet (Google) is that it might have something to do with a firewall on either sides of the connection. But I've tested it with all firewalls off, so this can't be that.

Comment: Well, the exception that is made for RaiseException. However, it comes down to "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ip:port"

Comment: Use telnet to test the connection, open command prompt, then telnet ipOfRemoteHost 32842 [enter], that will verify if listener is ok and no network issue (you might need to add Telnet Windows Feature if you haven't done that before)

Comment: You could maybe ping the destination IP to check that the host is up.  Your next step might be to download PuTTY and attempt to telnet to the destination IP and port.  Otherwise you could use a port mapper, this is an application that polls a range of IP addresses and reports back which ports are listening/open.  Otherwise, try connect to an endpoint on your own network.  Pick an SMTP, POP3 or a web server.  If you Google some basic info on talking to a particular service, it should talk back to you, if it does you know your code is working fine.

Comment: @Tomek, I can use telnet successfully to connect to the other client. So there should be no network issues, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see Socket.EndConnect() being called in the callback.
See this in MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.endconnect.aspx

Comment: Calling EndConnect() caused the application to generate an exception "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ip:port".

Comment: It seemed that it was a stupid mistake on my end. In a previous attempt to make it work, I bound the local TcpClient to a specific port. I altered that to make it use a port given by the system. However, I tried to use that port number to connect to the other instance of the program. After I altered that, it succeeded to connect. However, I think your call about EndConnect() did have something to do with it, so I'll mark this as the answer. :)